# Replacing html tag with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match  tags using preg_replace. The regex used is: `<video[^>]*>(.*?)</video>`

But I'm getting a server warning: `Message: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier ']'`

Any clues on why?

Also, How could I modify the regex so it can match [video] tags instead?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't parse HTML with regex. For more info on why, read the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

For the BBCode stuff, you could use the BBCode extension if you have access to PECL. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

Comment: Thanks, there's not much documentation regarding this but I'll see around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to delimit your regex, as required in the `preg_` functions. Usually we would write `/regex/`, but any delimiters will do.

Since your regex contains `/`, I'll go for `%`, to avoid escaping it.

```
%<video[^>]*>(.*?)</video>%
```

Of course, watch out for the perils of trying to mess with HTML via regex. There will be issues. As always.

If you want `[video]` instead, just replace all `<>` with `[]` - but remember to escape them, since `[` and `]` are significant in regular expressions!

```
%\[video[^\]]*\](.*?)\[/video\]%
```

Comment: Thanks a billion! About the html.. I know, but it's just a quick replace for video code. Shouldn't be too problematic.

Comment: @Ignacio - glad to help :) I'm sure you know, but please remember to click the check mark next to the answer once SO will let you :D Thanks!